# ngIf Display Button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking to display a button based on if the localstorage is equal to its value (complete).My localstorage.setItem('Level1', 'complete').  For some reason the *ngIf isn't working and I'm not sure why...

ts file

```
Level1: string;

constructor(){}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let Level1 = localStorage.getItem('Level1');
  }
```

**HTML**

```
      <div *ngIf="Level1 !== complete">
  <button clear class="button12" id="button1" ion-button color="stable" block large style="color:#000000;" (click)="openModal()">
    Player Button
  </button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="Level1 === complete">
<button clear class="button12complete" id="button2" ion-button color="stable" block large style="color:#000000;" (click)="openModal()">
    <!--<ion-icon name="american-football"></ion-icon> -->
    Player Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
*ngIf="Level1 !== 'complete'"
```

---

```
export class HomePage {
  Level1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.Level1 = 'complete';//localStorage.getItem('Level1');
  }

}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5xzwat?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)**

Comment: Worked - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

modify

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let Level1 = localStorage.getItem('Level1');
  }
```

to

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
this.Level1 = localStorage.getItem('Level1');


}
```

**Update:**: inject dependencies as well